# Create Database Record with PHP Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to write to a database with PHP and it's not working and I don't know why. Any help would be very much appreciated!

I've had a couple of people look at it with no avail so I'm hoping that a few extra eyes can help me find what is preventing it from working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Test </title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
<?php
$servername = 'localhost3306';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = 'database';


try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname', $username, $password);

    setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);d
    $sql = "INSERT INTO resgisterdusers(Password, FirstName, LastName, Hometown1, State1,
            Zip1, Hometown2, State2, Zip2, PhoneNum, Email, Car, GraduationMonth,
            GraduationYear, AccountActivated, DateActivated, ActivationCode, RouteID1, RouteID2);
    VALUES ('Password1', 'joe', 'sixpack', 'city', 'MT', '59595', '', '', '', '55555555555',
            'email@email.edu', '1', '05', '2012', '1', '2/28/2015', 'XXX', '', '2')";

    exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";

    }
catch(PDOException $ec
)
    {
    echo "Error!";
    getmessage();
        }

$conn = null;
?>
</p>
</body >


</html>
```

Comment: Don't use PDO often, but shouldn't it be `$conn->exec($sql);`?

Comment: How does it fail?  Is there an error?  Unexpected behavior?  Please describe the problem.

Comment: `exec($sql);` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: `setAttribute()` is a method of PDO, not a function. Same with `exec()`. And you have a `d` floating around at the end of your `setAttribute()` line.

Comment: I've honestly never seen so many errors in so few lines of code. Turning on error reporting would help a lot in debugging this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the semicolon before the word `VALUES` in your SQL Insert statement..

Comment: Nice catch. You might want to point to the other answers for the other problems.

Answer (score 2):

No it should be

```
$conn->query($sql)
```

But you should be using prepared statements if it's user input...

and this line needs to be changed

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);d
```

change it to

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Edit: You are welcome although I didn't completely have your solution. d_unknown had noticed the bonus semicolon in the query. Good eye, i completely missed it and this small screen isn't helping me any.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
exec($sql);
```

to this:

```
$conn->exec($sql);
```

Also, it seems `setAttribute` is a method of PDO also.

Change that to

```
$conn->setAttribute(...);
```

[PDO exec() method manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

[PDO setAttribute() method manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

There is also a `;` before the word `VALUES` in your sql.

Comment: Also `$conn->setAttribute(..`. There's a random d on the end of that line too.

Comment: I believe the exec function has to be used with a prepared statement right? It would be $conn->query() in this case instead of $conn->exec()

Comment: And update the catch clause to be `echo "Error!" . $ec->getMessage();`

Comment: I think there should be a `$conn->prepare($sql);` but I don't use PDO often. @Dallin

Comment: For some reason whenever we add "->" to our code, it doesn't work - rather it just prints everything onto the screen that appears after the ->. Does that make sense?